# Get Domain user membership for local group

Tags: c++, c, windows, active-directory, group-membership

I have a local group on my computer `Grp1` to which I want to check membership of domain users. I have already used `NetUserGetLocalGroups` for this. But the problem I encounter is when the domain user is not a direct member of the group `Grp1`. For example, let's say there are two domain groups say `DomainGrp1` and `DomainGrp2`. Now, my user `DomainUser1` is part of group `DomainGrp2` and the `DomainGrp2` is part of `DomainGrp1` and the group `DomainGrp1` is part of the local group `Grp1`. If I use this `NetUserGetLocalGroups` in the aforementioned scenario, the API doesn't enumerate `Grp1` for `DomainUser1` but in actual the `DomainUser1` is part of the `Grp1` indirectly.

Also please note that if the `DomainUser1` is directly member of `DomainGrp1` instead of `DomainGrp2` (with the `DomainGrp1` be the member of `Grp1`). The API enumerates the `Grp1` perfectly.  Could somebody help me with this problem?

I have tried impersonation using `LogonUser` API. But the problem I have is when the user is marked for changing password at next log on. Then the API returns false and hence I cannot get the impersonation token.

PS: I don't want to use any Directory Services API.

I could find similar problem on MSDN [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3984434e-7022-42ec-9157-b4dd2fad7256/netusergetlocalgroups-fails-returning-local-groups-in-case-if-the-user-is-in-a-nested-group-in-ad?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: You'll just have to iterate through the group memberships yourself.  Obviously, you'll need access to the domain (i.e., you can't be running in the context of a local user account) in order to do so.

Comment: That is a way provided that I am willing to interact with domain. But unfortunately I am not willing to do that because I can not ensure I will be having the knowledge of domain on client machine. Hence I don't want to make use of directory services API.

Comment: Obviously you can't do it without interacting with the domain - that's where the information you want is stored.  But you don't necessarily need to use the DS API, e.g., see NetLocalGroupGetMembers and NetGroupGetUsers.

Comment: Please see the question once again. I have already used the NetUserGetLocalGroups. NetLocalGroupGetMembers  works in similar way. I have tried that as well.

Comment: NetLocalGroupGetMembers should give you the domain groups belonging to the local group of interest, and NetGroupGetUsers should be able to enumerate the users in those domain groups.  But you'd have to experiment as to whether you can deal with nested domain groups that way, I'm not sure about that.  If not, you'll just have to use the Directory Services API - Microsoft even have [existing sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676317(v=vs.85).aspx)  that does exactly what you need, so I don't see why you're so reluctant to use it.